# Question mark shown over ethernet icon

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I have a computer that is using an Ethernet connection. Recently I have changed routers and had to set it up with a new static IP. When I had typed in all the information to set up a static ip, the ethernet connection started showing a question mark over it. Hostname -I shows the static IP I set up, and on the list of connected devices on the router I can see my computer is connected. But I still cannot access the internet through Firefox or through a ping.

Comment: The ? indicates an error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and: `route -n` and: `systemd-resolve --status | grep 'DNS Servers' -A2` I suspect that you omitted DNS nameservers in your static setup.

Comment: @chili555 yes I had forgotten to put in the DNS servers, thank you :)

Comment: In the interest of helping others with the same issue search for and find the solution, I shall propose an answer that I hope you will accept: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark typically means that the computer is connected to the router but does not yet have access to the internet. In many cases, this is because DNS nameservers are not properly set. Check:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns from the first, but not the second, then DNS resolution is not working.

If you wish to use a static IP address, you may do so by editing connections in Network Manager. In this case, if you set up a fixed address, you are responsible to specify DNS nameservers, as well. I suggest:

[image]

Of course, substitute your exact details here. Reboot and test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

You should be all set.